# What is causing Auth.verifyIdToken: TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use [Auth.verifyIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken) on Node.js to authenticate users on the server. However, the promise rejects with the error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined*. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined* came from my code in the `then` function of the promise returned by **Auth.verifyIdToken**. This error made the `catch` function of the promise run. The **Auth.verifyIdToken** method itself doesn't have an error.

To catch errors from **Auth.verifyIdToken** only, call `catch` before your code in `then`.